# Is there a way to suppress [Vue-warn] in prop validation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I need to display custom validator message on prop. Along with custom error I also see default Vue warning **[Vue-warn]**. Is there away to suppress [Vue-warn]:

My prop look like this:

```js
props: {
  mode: String,
  default: h,
  validator: val => {
    if(['s','y','z'].includes(v)) {
      return true
    }
    else {
      console.error("Possible values for mode are: 's', 'y' or 'z'");
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning only appears because the `validator` returns `false`.

To avoid the warning message in the console, return `true` instead:

```js
props: {
  mode: String,
  default: h,
  validator: val => {
       
    if(!['s','y','z'].includes(v)) {
      console.error("Possible values for mode are: 's', 'y' or 'z'");
    }       
    return true
  }
}
```